# Why is an empty function call in python around 15% slower for dynamically compiled python code

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic, python-2.7, micro-optimization

This is pretty bad micro-optimizing, but I'm just curious. It usually doesn't make a difference in the "real" world.

So I'm compiling a function (that does nothing) using `compile()` then calling `exec` on that code and getting a reference to the function I compiled. Then I'm executing it a couple million times and timing it. Then repeating it with a local function. Why is the dynamically compiled function around 15% slower (on python 2.7.2) for just the call?

```
import datetime
def getCompiledFunc():
  cc = compile("def aa():pass", '<string>', 'exec')
  dd = {}
  exec cc in dd
  return dd.get('aa')

compiledFunc = getCompiledFunc()  
def localFunc():pass


def testCall(f):
  st = datetime.datetime.now()
  for x in xrange(10000000): f()
  et = datetime.datetime.now()
  return (et-st).total_seconds()

for x in xrange(10):
  lt = testCall(localFunc)
  ct = testCall(compiledFunc)
  print "%s %s %s%% slower" % (lt, ct, int(100.0*(ct-lt)/lt))
```

The output I'm getting is something like:

```
1.139 1.319 15% slower
```

Comment: context switching? I.e. when you call the compiled function, you are still going into a new scope, executing the function, and returning the result from the scope? (i'm no python expert, just a guess)

Comment: Your measurements are off.  Use `timeit` to get unbiased measurements, and the results will be identical (I tried, they are).  The two function objects are indistunguishable, and they have identical byte code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Answer with counter microbenchmark?

Comment: @SvenMarnach It's a little bit less of a difference when using `timeit`, but it's still there (6% on my machine).  I used `timeit.repeat('a()', setup="from __main__ import compiledFunc as a", number=10000000)` and similarly for `localFunc` instead of `compiledFunc `

Comment: I could reproduce this strange behaviour in one case in Python 2.6, but not in 2.7.  Other tests didn't reproduce this, even in 2.6.  Unfortunately I don't have the time to properly write this up now, but definitely something strange is going on.  And again, except for the associated filen ames and the function names, the two function objects are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: The function objects have different `__globals__`. If I instead `exec` the code object in `globals()`, the local vs compiled run at the same speed (2.7.2, Windows).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *[dis.dis()](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#module-dis)* function shows that the code object for each version is identical:

```
aa
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
localFunc
 10           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the difference is in the function object.  I compared each of the fields (func_doc, func_closure, etc) and the one that is different is func_globals.  In other words, `localFunc.func_globals != compiledFunc.func_globals`.

There is a cost for supplying your own dictionary instead of the built-in globals (the former has to be looked up when a stack frame is created on each call and the latter can be referenced directly by the C code which already knows about the default builtin globals dictionary).

This is easy verified by changing the *exec* line in your code to:

```
exec cc in globals(), dd
```

With **that** change, the timing difference goes away.

Mystery solved!